# Can inadequate amount of water in body, affect CBC test results?

Tags: hemoglobin, cbc-complete-blood-count

I remember once my father took a CBC test, and his hemoglobin was strangely higher than that of one day before. We thought the test could be erroneous, but the lab's technician said it's probably because of not drinking enough water! Is there such a connection?

Comment: Yes it CAN, that's one type of hemoconcentration, and usually all 3 cell lines increase proportionally in that case.  But that doesn't mean that IS why it happened, there are many possible reasons.  You need to ask your doctor. The lab tech's speculation is not a replacement for a medical professional's analysis.

Comment: Also, your title refers to drinking a lot of water (more than usual) but the tech's comment was not drinking enough water - the opposite. Please edit to make the question consistent.